# After upgrade to 15.04 screen resolution stuck at low graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg, resolution

I was running 12.04 32bit on an old Asus laptop with ATI X1200 graphics and upgraded stepwise to 15.04. Somewhere along the way the graphics got stuck at low resolution. The upgraded system uses the correct video drivers (generic) and the display manager is correct. Actually, I have used every advice on every forum but xrandr keeps reporting a single res of 800x600 even after reinstalling and resetting everything related to the display subsystem.

When running the live CD the number of possible resolutions are reported correctly and everything works fine. In fact, all devices and settings reported are the same as on the installed system.

I've had the low res problem before and finally had to reinstall from scratch to fix it.

What makes that after running failsafe graphics / reconfigure graphics following a recovery boot the system subsequently only reports a single low resolution which can't be undone. Is there no way to manually re-detect and re-install the graphic subsystem similar to what the installation procedure does?

Comment: The last time I wanted to updade graphics, I joust give up and reinstaled the whole os.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with my Radeon HD 4650, and spent a lot of time looking for the solution. I finally found help [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166037).

As instructed, I removed the word `nomodeset` from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and then regenerated grub by doing `grub-mkcofnig -o /tmp/grub.cfg`.

Note: I did the editing of `grub.cfg` with `gedit`, which I started in terminal with the command `gksudo gedit`. That enables you to edit system files (people seem to have different opinions on what is the right way to start gedit with root rights).

Now my display is properly recognized and I have all the resolution options available.