# Radeon HD screen resolution is low

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.04, radeon

I have an old video card and seems it works somehow on the latest Ubuntu 15 (downloaded today). As I understand, the card is supported by the [open source driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), and officially the card is not supported by vendor anymore. However, seems the driver only supports 1024*768 resolution, while my monitor supports up to 1680*1050. "Screen display" system settings shows it as "Unknown Display". Could I do something with it or I just need a new card?

`lspci` shows the device as `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]`.

I've tried the answer here, but it didn't help: [After upgrade to 15.04 screen resolution stuck at low graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640325/after-upgrade-to-15-04-screen-resolution-stuck-at-low-graphics)

I've tried to install `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates` - it breaks the X, login screen appears in terrible resolution (I gess 640*480) and I cannot login at all.

Comment: Old tutorial, but it might work: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440323

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've tried it too. The driver installation fails with error (missing include file), seems it is not compatible with the latest kernel source code.

Comment: Maybe not then. You might have better luck on 14.04. When 16.04 comes out, though, you're gonna want a newer card.

Comment: @Zacharee1 That's sad. Why is video card always a problem? Could you recommend how to choose a simple card which has no problems with Linux?

Comment: I would avoid NVIDIA, since it has huge problems with Ubuntu. As long as you get an AMD card from 2012 or later you should be fine.